# How do I detect falling people with a smart watch?

Tags: android, sony-smartwatch

I am a senior in computer engineering and I have a question for you. For my graduation project, I chose a smart watch and fall detection project, but I don't know much about it. Can you help me determine what methods or hardware tools I can use to develop this project? I found out that it was an asteroidOS operating system for the smart watch, but I still haven't figured out how to detect the fall.

Why u delete my android tag ?? I'll detect fall and will show on mobile app.

Comment: AsteroidOS is not android, so this question is mistagged

Comment: As for what you can do-  the accelerometer is the only sensor that will really help you, but writing an algorithm around it that detects falls vs sudden stops or riding an elevator is too broad for this site.

Comment: So how do I code the smart watch?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about asteroidOS. But this would be the approach I would take. Train a ML/DL model based on the Accelerometer and gyroscope values or analyse the both signals and find a condition which indicates the fall.

Here is a great paper you check: https://storm.cis.fordham.edu/~gweiss/papers/bhi-ar-2016.pdf

Accelerometers in mobile phones are used to detect the orientation of the phone. The gyroscope, or gyro for short, adds an additional dimension to the information supplied by the accelerometer by tracking rotation or twist.

An accelerometer measures linear acceleration of movement, while a gyro on the other hand measures the angular rotational velocity. Both sensors measure rate of change; they just measure the rate of change for different things.

In practice, that means that an accelerometer will measure the directional movement of a device but will not be able to resolve its lateral orientation or tilt during that movement accurately unless a gyro is there to fill in that info.

Accelerometers are also used to provide 'steps' information for a 'health' application. Probably you can get some inspiration by researching this domain.

Comment: I'm already checkin  health applications but they want it too much money :) I cant find opensource

Comment: https://github.com/seemoo-lab/fitness-app

https://github.com/nRFMesh/nRF5x-smartwatches

Here are 2 open source repos that I found on github. Please take a look...